# Why does my hall light flicker when i turn my bedroom fan off?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

We have a brand new house. We have found so many things we've had to fix already ugh! But, right outside our bedroom is the hallway with an LED light. When it is off and we turn the switch off in our bedroom for our ceiling fan the hall light will flicker. I just want to make sure this won't be concern for a fire as we have two growing children.

Comment: What type of switch controls the hall light?  Can you change the bulb?

Comment: So if you didn't have growing children then would this be less of a concern?

Comment: Does it flicker momentarily when you turn off your ceiling fan or continuously?   Is the hallway fixture with the LED on a dimmer?

Comment: Try replacing it with a tungsten bulb. If that solves the problem which I believe it will it is the LED bulb sensitive to the transients from the fan motor when being turned off. There is nothing to worry about, you can dry a different bulb, maybe one that is dimmable.